# Why can't rake routes be more helpful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

When you type rake routes in the shell it displays a nice list of routes:

```
      new_edition GET    /editions/new(.:format)           editions#new
     edit_edition GET    /editions/:id/edit(.:format)      editions#edit
         edition GET    /editions/:id(.:format)           editions#show
                 PUT    /editions/:id(.:format)           editions#update
              DELETE /editions/:id(.:format)           editions#destroy
```

This is very helpful but why not show the actual code needed to be used in the app as well for example

```
 edition GET    /editions/:id(.:format)  editions#show  edition_path()
```

I am guess it is because there may be more to it then this but the general issue is when I look at the examples give for the routes I have look up an example of how it is expressly coded to understand what the route means...

Comment: Because appending `_path` or `_url` isn't that difficult to remember?

Comment: Thanks Dave.  You are right and with the more understanding I can see better how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `xxx_path` directly isn't the only option you have.

Rails offers you resourceful way of building urls via `polymorpic_path/_url` methods. These methods are used by many other helpers, like:

```
link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @user]     # instead of edit_user_path(@user)
redirect_to Product                # instead of products_path
form_for [@order, @product] do |f| # instead of order_product_path(@order, @product)
visit url_for [:preview, @invoice] # instead of preview_invoice_path(@invoice)
```

So, by looking at `preview_invoice` prefix you know what to do, but the exact way is up to you.

Comment: Thank you jdoe.  Your answer helped me understand the options and how why they are presenting what they are in the rake routes command.  Really appreciated it.

Comment: The question should be closed, but it would be a pity to lose this answer :)

Comment: @Arsen7 Thanks, your comment is also nonconstructive! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have all the info needed. The first column tells you the prefix of the name of the route helper (new_edition, for instance). All you need to do is add `_path` or `_url` to have the complete method name.

Then, you have some routes with no indication regarding the corresponding helper method name: it's because it matches the same URL as another route, only the HTTP verb (GET, POST) changes. So you'd have to add `method: 'delete'` for instance to your call.

Comment: Thank you ksol - appreciate the answer.